# Export json data to formatted csv file

Tags: postgresql

I have a column in my database table which stores a JSON object. I'm having trouble finding how to export the JSON object to a formatted CSV file. For example if the JSON looked like so:

```
{
 "name": "test",
  "age": "23"
}
```

Is there a way to export this to make name and age its own specific column in the CSV file?

The closest command I found exports the JSON object, it just doesn't make each key value in the JSON object its own column. Is this possible?

Here is what I have so far.

```
Copy (Select * From form_submissions) To 'path/to/whatever' With CSV DELIMITER ',';
```

Answer (score 1):

You should *unpack* the json column, use the operator `->>` [(Get JSON object field as text)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html)

Example:

```
copy (
    select json_column->>'name', json_column->>'age' 
    from form_submissions) 
to 'path/to/whatever' 
with csv delimiter ',';
```

Comment: how can I solve this problem if I have a dynamic number of keys?

Comment: You should select all the keys that may appear in json objects.

Comment: And what if I don't know? As in the keys may vary and which are a priori unknown.

Comment: The subject is too broad for a comment. In short, you need a preliminary step to determine the keys.